How to fix SSL Exception Issue while embedding power bi contents in a react and java spring application
We have Embedded Power bi Report inside a React & Java Spring boot based application using App Owns Data via Service Principal method. The application is hosted in Azure Kubernetes Service with a mapped subdomain cherrywork.com.
We can access the application using this URL, but the power bi contents embedded within this application is not visible. 
While looking at the issue, we got this error message : message: "com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset"
There is no firewall restriction from my organization.
Using the Azure library in Java to try to obtain an access token with the following code:
ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(             Constants.clientId,             ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(Constants.appSecret))       .authority(Constants.authorityUrl + Constants.tenantId)       .build();
 
ClientCredentialParameters clientCreds = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(             Collections.singleton(Constants.scopeBase))       .build();
 
// Acquire new AAD token IAuthenticationResult result = app.acquireToken(clientCreds).get(); 

When I run the application on my local machine, it works fine. But once my organization deploys it to Azure Kubernetes Service, we get the following error :
2024-03-27 05:05:46.130 ERROR 1 --- [       Thread-2] c.m.a.m.ConfidentialClientApplication    : [Correlation ID: 26588393-a78f-4fe8-b8a3-b3350bead014] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequest(HttpHelper.java:68) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.sendInstanceDiscoveryRequest(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:119) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.doInstanceDiscoveryAndCache(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:135) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.getMetadataEntry(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:42) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.getAuthorityWithPrefNetworkHost(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:32) [msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:59) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59) [msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17) [msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604) [na:1.8.0_382]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_382]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:274) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1401) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1309) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.net.
www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.net.
www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.net.
www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1572)
~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.net.
www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500)
~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.net.
www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.readResponseFromConnection(DefaultHttpClient.java:107) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.executeHttpGet(DefaultHttpClient.java:47) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.send(DefaultHttpClient.java:35) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequestWithRetries(HttpHelper.java:86) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequest(HttpHelper.java:64) ~[msal4j-1.7.1.jar!/:1.7.1]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
    ... 23 common frames omitted

Need help to resolve this issue asap. Please mention the steps that we should follow to resolve this issue.
We checked all the permissions:

app registration in Azure AD
Api permission for the App to Power BI Service
Client Secret
security group
Power BI Admin Portal -> Allowed to embed content in app & Service Principal to use Power BI Apis ( added security group)
power bi workspace access to Registered Application
Used Embedded URL, Embedded Token, Report ID to fetch the report

